# How do you trace a raster image and make paths in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app, image-trace

How do you turn a raster image into vector paths in Sketch?

Comment: @eastside: don't bother editing old questions that got voted to be closed, focus on open questions that can benefit from the attention.

Comment: You can trace images on https://vectormagic.com/ for a $10/month.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Sketch doesn't have that feature yet. You could use Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape to trace the image and then import it into Sketch.

Comment: If you don't have Illustrator and don't want to buy it just for this feature, use Inkscape -- it has the same feature.

Comment: Either that or just use the Ai Trial but Inkscape is probably the better Option(edited my answer, Thanks)

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator is recommended but if you still want to do it in Sketch here is the way:

 **Suppose this is your image**
[image]

**I want to trace the top he is wearing. I'll simply draw a rectangle**
[image]

**Double click on it to see the nodes. You'll also see the inspector on the right has changed. You can make it curve or straight lines as you like. To add a new node just click on the side from where you want to start a new node.**
[image]

**Here is how it looks like. Not a perfect one but you get the idea.**
[image]